# How to update data with a JOINed tables using Codeigniter's Active Record CI2?

Tags: php, mysql, join, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Is it possbile to update data with a JOINed tables using Codeigniter's Active Record CI2? I have running code and I want to convert to Codeigniter's Active Record.

```
public function update_table($job_id, $om_id, $recipient_id)
{
    $query = "UPDATE table1 AS t1
                       INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
                               ON t1.om_id = t2.id
                SET    t2.read_date = NOW()
                WHERE  t2.ref_table_id = $job_id
                AND    t1.om_id = $om_id
                AND    t2.recipient_id = $recipient_id
                AND    t2.read_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";

    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

I try like this but doesn't work.

```
public function update_table($job_id, $om_id, $recipient_id)
{
    $this->db->set('t2.read_date', NOW());

    $this->db->where('t2.ref_table_id', $job_id);
    $this->db->where('t1.om_id', $om_id);
    $this->db->where('t2.recipient_id', $recipient_id);
    $this->db->where('t2.read_date', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
    $this->db->where('t2.om_id = t1.id');
    $this->db->update('table1 AS t1, table AS t2');

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try this..

supply the $condition as array... same with the data that you wanted to update.

```
function update_data($table, $data, $condition)
{
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->update($table, $data); 
}
```

Comment: I guess this is just the simple way on CI, where should I put the join clause?

Comment: @VonnGarcia hmmm, as far as I know you can only use `join` when selecting data... you're only updating the `t2.read_date`... so basically you only need to do a `where clause` on `t1.om_id` since `om_id` is already a foreign key on your `table2 why not do a `where clause` on `t2.om_id` directly.... you're making it hard on yourself...